# What constitutes "using a website" in Canada?

Tags: canada

[image: This is a fairly boilerplate disclaimer about cookies.]
This is a disclaimer found on the Qt website. The "Read More" link doesn't contain any information about what exactly "using" the website involves, either.

What do I have to do in order for my consent to the use of cookies on this website to be confirmed?

Comment: Load the website? By accessing the website, you're using the website.

Answer (score 1):

They sent a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation) with that message.

If you connect to any site that is interested in that cookie it will request that your computer send that cookie, and your computer will comply unless you take steps to stop it.

Following any link on the page including the "Read More" would likely involve sending the cookie back to them by default.

Sending a cookie back seems something like consenting to using them.

Answer (score 1):

That site is **claiming** that by accessing the site, a user is consenting to have cookies set and read. Whether that claim is legally valid is another question. Under the various EU national laws to implement the e-privacy directive it would not be, because those laws use the same standard for consent as the GDPR, and simple access is not good enough to demonstrate consent. If Canada has a privacy law that regulates cookie use, I don't know of it.